# Border/backdrop behind a ImageView

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to achieve the following result:

[image]

It's an ImageView with a blue border/backdrop, can you guys help me?

This is the current layout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:id="@+id/image_logo"
        android:src="@drawable/fb_icon"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:src="@color/colorPrimary" />


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:src="@color/colorAccent" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what i needed!

Comment: @NileshRathod, Hi. Your answer is correct and acceptable, but i would like to point that instead of user margin top, left, bottom and top. You can achieve it by only margin. No need to increase the line of code. What you say?

Comment: @ChiragRaval agree with you sir

Answer (score 0):

Create a file shadow_rect.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item >
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
            <corners android:radius="0dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:right="1dp"  android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
            <corners android:radius="1dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

And the use this as android:background="@drawable/shadow_rect within your Imageview.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer, you are looking for. Here the blank person is the image which i have used from my project. Same as the color. You can use your own image and color for the same.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:background="@color/blue_biometric"
        android:layout_height="57dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:id="@+id/image_logo"
        android:src="@drawable/blank_person"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left" />



</RelativeLayout>
```